# How can I track print competition scores in Lightroom via Metadata?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, competitions

I've recently started submitting my work into local and regional print competitions.  As I get results, I thought it might be nice to be able to keep track of that along with the photo's metadata in Lightroom.

I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this - are there any built in metadata fields that would be appropriate?  Are you aware of plugins that provide this functionality?  Is there a way to add a new metadata field that I could use for this purpose?

Comment: Not sure, but the IPTC data has fields for job/event, you could probably use some of those

Comment: Can you explain what the difficulty is other than putting a metatag depending on the score (Score1, Score2, etc) or using Stars?

Comment: @Itai Stars won't work since I use them for other things plus the score is numeric (80, 78, 84, etc).  If there's a way to add arbitrary new metadata fields, that would work, but I don't know how to do it. Leave that as an answer and win... :)

Comment: @Itai I assume the problem is that those fields are visible in the "sync metadata" dialog but not in the regular IPTC metadata view.   Also it would not be possible to search for photos with a score (say) over 90%.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the IPTC specifications linked to from the [IPTC site](http://www.iptc.org/cms/site/index.html?channel=CH0099) which links to the [IPTC Photo Metadata specifications](http://www.iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata-201007.pdf).

I could not find a perfect matching data field but I would suggest using the  `Keywords` field, which is free text and then use specific and consistent description: `competition_score:84` which would allow you to use regular expressions to search through all the scores in all images.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to write an add-in to to extend the metadata.
I have done it, so I know from experience that it can work.

Comment: Welcome to Photography Stack Exchange! Could you explain how your add-in works, or link to it if you have it available online, so that future visitors might benefit from it? (Your answer will remain on here long after ahockley finds the solution he's looking for!) Since we are a Q&A site, not a traditional forum, we try to keep answers useful for every person who lands on the page.